# Cannot open files from CD burned in Ubuntu

Tags: dvd

I have burned a dvd in ubuntu some time ago from a machine I longer have. The disk contains images and pdf files. I have tested that the disk was working properly on Ubuntu but when I try to open it from windows machines all files appear unrecongized. The file structure is readable but the files are not recognized(cannot be opened) by the applications. I have tried data recovery software but no use. Is there any way I can retrieve my files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Windows isn't able to read your files from the DVD, but if Ubuntu is able, then the solution should be simple. Boot Ubuntu and access the files. Ubuntu is also able to access Windows' filesystems, so you can copy them onto your Windows file system.